# Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, anaconda

Recently upgraded Anaconda to 4.4.0. But when I turned on debugger in Eclipse there is an error message:`Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt5'`and:

```
ImportError: 
Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
PyQt4 >= 4.7 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
and only one is imported per session.

Currently-imported Qt library:   None
PyQt4 installed:                 False
PyQt5 installed:                 True
PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       False
Tried to load:                   ['pyqtdefault']
```

I tried to install PyQT4 by `conda install pyqt=4` but another error was returned:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pyqt 4* -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse go to `Preferences > PyDev > Interactive Console`.
From drop-down list choose appropriate **PyQt** version in your case it's **PyQt5**

[image]

Apply changes and after that it should work. If error still persist then run below command:

`conda update --all`